# My Facebook gallery suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to make a FB gallery that gets album images from FB page. A few days ago I have coded it and works fine, but only loaded first 50 albums. Since yesterday, it's not working. When test below code I couldn't get anything from my FB page.

```
 $string = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/fbpage/albums?fields=id,count');
echo $string;
```

But if I changed the url something like,

```
$string = file_get_contents('http://google.com/')
echo $string;
```

Then I can get the contents.

Comment: Are you using an access token with the request?

Comment: Can you please explain in your question what exactly you are getting back instead? Is there an exception being thrown, or do you get an error message back from the API, instead of data?